# Why am I getting a 6 second hang on ASP.NET AJAX page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, debugging, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET AJAX page that for some reason on the LIVE version it is getting a 6 second pause in the javascript used by asp.net for it's ajax capabilities. This is not happening on the local copy.

Here is a picture of the hang time and the ScriptResource.axd scripts that seem to be causing it.

Anybody know what's going on?

Here's a link to a bigger photo

[full size photo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13675289/hangtime.png)

Thanks, 
Thomas

[image: javascript delay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously you are using Ajax. Is there any "special" resource loaded in powerSearch.aspx? Also, please trace the scripts executed when going through that page. If some of them has to wait until the page is ready, and the page is taking time to load (due to a missing, or big resource) then you have to wait the six seconds. Hope that helps,